# Embedded image does not show in Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I follow the guide on the official [Xamarin website](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images) telling how to embed the image into the cross-platform app. I build the app only for Android platform.

Unfortunately, the image is not shown during debug on my Sony D5803 Z3 Compact or in Android 7.1 emulator. I use VS 2017 RC on Windows 10. All the previous HelloWorld apps e.g. with downloading the picture via URI worked well on my phone.

I would be grateful for any help or advice how to troubleshoot the problem.

The image `picture.jpg` has set the build property `embedded resource` (in Polish `Akcja kompilacji: osadzony zasób`)

[image: setting page with build property set to embedded resource]

I can see the images in the debug folder as shown in the screenshot

[image: pictures visible in debug folder]

This is the XAML page I use to show the image:

**ImageEmbeddedPAge.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:markupExtensions="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.MarkupExtensions;assembly=HelloWorld.Droid"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.ImageEmbeddedPAge">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image x:Name="image"
               Source="{markupExtensions:ImageResource Source=HelloWorld.Images.picture.jpg}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**ImageResourceExtension.cs** in folder MarkupExtensions

```
namespace HelloWorld.MarkupExtensions
{
    [ContentProperty("Source")]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);
            return imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new ImageEmbeddedPAge();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: I created a clean solution with Cross-Platform app and the problem still persists - no image shown.

Comment: You should use what is described in using Native Resolutions as you are using a Shared Project and not a Portable Class Library.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with @Cheesebaron, since you created a Xamarin.Forms shared projecrt, we need to place resolution images in [specially-named directories](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in Android project, these specially-named directories are all placed under the `Resources`-> `Drawable` folder in the Android project.

If you want to use an embedded image, we need to use a Portable Lib for each platfrom, or just create a Xamarin.Forms portable project. If you want to create a PCL by yourself, than please be careful with the targets of this PCL, normally it should be like following image so can it be used for different platforms:

[image]

And finally to embed an image in a project, by default the image will have `Build Action: None`, please set it to `Build Action: EmbeddedResource`.

The reason why we cannot place images in a shared project is that:

> The shared project reference shows up under the References node in the Solution Explorer, but the code and assets in the shared project are treated as if they were files linked into the main project.

The images then are treated as files not resources.